# Sorting with sequelize.js by amount of positive values in row

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

There can be multiple columns with different types (boolean, timestamp ...) that will take part in sorting.

**Sorting:**
the more columns in the row with positive values, the higher this row should be in the results

Example:

**Table:**

```
0, “text”, true, ‘ ‘2019-02-04 12:35:17.655+02’’
0, “text”, false, null
2, “text”, true, ‘ ‘2019-02-04 12:35:17.655+02’’
0, null, false, null
0, “text”, true, null
```

**Result:**

```
2, “text”, true, ‘ ‘2019-02-04 12:35:17.655+02’’
0, “text”, true, ‘ ‘2019-02-04 12:35:17.655+02’’
0, “text”, true, null
0, “text”, false, null
0, null, false, null
```

I think we need to somehow count the positive values in the columns for each row, and then sort them by this value. Just how to write this in the request with sequelize.js or in postgres I do not know.

Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `order` attribute in your query to sort results based on a key. For example

```
Products.findAll({
        where: { isSoldOut: false },
        // Sort products by prices in descending order
        // Most expensive (highest values) first
        order: [
            ['price', 'DESC'] 
        ],
        attributes: ['id', 'name', 'price', 'image']
 });
```

Comment: But how to sort in this order ?
"The more columns in the row with positive values, the higher this row should be in the results"

Comment: Using the `order` attribute in your query like I said. This will return the sorted results in a descending order (the ones with higher values go to the top)